# Changed logged in as for SSH to Bitbucket

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket for version control but lately I haven't been able to pull or push commits. I get the error:

```
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So after looking around I found and ran the command `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org` which displayed me logged in as another user, say `userX`.

`UserX` is my personal account username. The computer and account I'm trying to work on is a corporate account, `UserY`. Somehow I have managed to log my personal account in.

If I run `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` it displays the correct work details.

Does anyone know how I can changed the "logged in as" so I can connect to Bitbucket?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup ssh keys in bitbucket.

- #### Generate ssh-keys

  ```
  # generate ssh keys. if you have any don't overwrite
  > ssh-keygen 

  Generating public/private rsa key pair.
  Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa):
  Created directory '/Users/emmap1/.ssh'.
  Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
  Enter same passphrase again:
  Your identification has been saved in /Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa.
  Your public key has been saved in /Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
  The key fingerprint is:
  4c:80:61:2c:00:3f:9d:dc:08:41:2e:c0:cf:b9:17:69 emmap1@myhost.local
  The key's randomart image is:
  +--[ RSA 2048]----+
  |*o+ooo.          |
  |.+.=o+ .         |
  |. *.* o .        |
  | . = E o         |
  |    o . S        |
  |   . .           |
  |     .           |
  |                 |
  |                 |
  +-----------------+
  ```
- Now copy the public key and save it under your bitbucket account

  ```
  > cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```
- Go to your bitbucket account and under your gravatar open the menu and you will see `SSH KEYS` section
- Add new key and paste the key into the the the text box

[image]

- Change an existing repo from HTTPS to the SSH protocol if you using https and not ssh
- try a `git fetch` and answer yes if you are being promp to add the key to the know hosts file.

Comment: I tried all this and I still end up with the same fatal error. All the configs for user name and email point to my work credentials. However when I run the command `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org` it shows me logged in as my personal user. Which I suspect is the reason why the conflict and the fatal error.

Comment: Once you use ssh key the server will identify you as the user with the key. if its still not working verify that you have write persmission on the bitbucket server

Comment: This is strange as I am down as an "Admin" and have full access.

Comment: Verify under the project and rep that you have right acess. the default is read only even if you are admin, the admin is only for bitbucket GUI

Comment: Hi CodeWizard, thanks for all this info. I had tried everything you suggested and couldn't get the error to go away.

Then after thinking about this for a while I realized I still had the old SSH keys on my work laptop, hence why the new key wasn't working on the desktop. 

I removed all keys from all devices, ran the above instructions again and now it all appears to be working.

Thanks for all the guidance to get this working, much appreciated.